# Google OAuth tokens randomly stop working

Tags: oauth, google-api, google-oauth, google-signin, google-api-php-client

I have an application that is available on iOS, Android, and Desktop (via Electron) which all have features that depend on a Google OAuth flow.

I decided to make all of the apps redirect to an Angular web app for completing the OAuth journey which then successfully redirects back into whichever app the user came from.

Just to clarify immediately, my app is successfully verified by Google and it is set to production mode.

These are scopes which I use:

```
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.phonenumbers.read',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.other.readonly',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl',
```

Below is a step-by-step breakdown of the OAuth journey:

1. User clicks on UI within my frontend app to connect their Google account.
2. Frontend calls my backend (PHP Laravel) to generate a URL where the user can authenticate.
3. Frontend sends the user to the URL in their default web browser.
4. User enters their Google account credentials and gives consent to all the permissions/scopes.
5. User is sent to the configured redirect URI which is an Angular web app that captures the auth code.
6. Angular web app sends the auth code to my backend to validate the OAuth process such as generating refresh/access tokens etc.
7. My backend responds to the Angular app successfuly.
8. Angular app finally proceeds to redirect the user back to the app which they come from such as iOS, Android, or Desktop.
9. User is now authenticated and the OAuth process is complete while all the Google tokens are persisted safely in my backend.

All of the above works perfectly fine across all of the apps.

Later when the user is interacting with a feature which depends on Google such as for example their Google Calendar Events, my frontend calls my backend which in turn calls Google's REST APIs using that user's persisted access token and then serves it back to the frontend app.

**Important Note:**

- Since as you can see above that the OAuth process is all done in the Angular web app, I did not need to implement the Google OAuth SDKs on my iOS, Android, or Desktop apps.
- However on the Google API Dashboard I had to generate 3 separate web OAuth clients, one for each app. This should have not been necessary since I can set multiple Redirect URIs for 1 web OAuth client but I was facing a weird bug which seemingly did not go away until I separated them.
- So for example when iOS goes through the OAuth flow, the client ID for the iOS web client is used and so on.

[Image of 3 web clients on Google API Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6Lw9.png)

**So what is the problem?**

For some reason at random the OAuth credentials stop working. Sometimes it takes weeks to happen, sometimes days. I've been trying to find a pattern of what causes it and the closest clue I have is if the user performs SSO/OAuth across the different frontend apps perhaps. So for example they do it on Desktop and then later also perform an SSO login on their iOS app.

Or is it possible that Google is noticing this OAuth user originating from multiple different seemingly web origins so it's randomly revoking the tokens?

Everywhere I look online people mention that refresh tokens on a verified app in production mode should not expire unless the user's password is reset or they revoke the app manually, all of which are not the case for me.

Lastly to note, the same exact procedure is used with Microsoft and it works without this problem occurring. So it's specifically happening with Google OAuth only.

---

**UPDATE (30/06/2022)**

At some point for some reason randomly, my backend is unable to refresh the access token at server side. It throws the following error message when attempting to refresh the access token:

{'error' => 'unauthorized_client', 'error_description' => 'Unauthorized'}

Comment: What error are you receiving from Google when this happens?

Comment: @BluntJackson As far as I can gather currently this is the error:

"error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Invalid Credentials",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "authError",
        "location": "Authorization",
        "locationType": "header"
      }
    ],
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }

Comment: I have placed better monitoring in the code on this area so if I notice any change in the error, I will post it back here.

Comment: I don't understand the unpredictable time component; I gather this is happening with your own test accounts, so you can be 100% sure the user is not logging out in some other way?  The other thing to log would be what your parameters are to make sure there isn't some code path or race condition that is ending up with a null or invalid credential.

Comment: @BluntJackson These are actually real accounts with users in a production environment but in "early access". And as mentioned my app is verified by Google as well. Yet still this issue happens to people randomly.

Can you elaborate regarding "some code path or race condition that is ending up with a null or invalid credential".

Comment: Not without seeing your code! I can only speculate unless you share actual code or with reproducible effects. Have you reached out to Google developer support?

Comment: Yes I've shared the matter with Google Developer Support and am now awaiting a call with them soon.

Comment: UPDATE: I can confirm at some point my backend is unable to refresh the access token server side. It throws the following error message: {'error' => 'unauthorized_client', 'error_description' => 'Unauthorized'}

Comment: But it still appears to be at random because I have tested forcefully generating a new access token before actually necessary and it works fine. But 100% the problem occurs when the backend is unable to refresh the access token at some point. I don't why that happens still.

Comment: @ZanaAziz Do you find a solution ? I have the same issue :/

Answer (score 0):

When you generating access and refresh token, you have to store it safely.

The access token have a short lifetime (1 hour). You have to control if it stay valid before using it. To do it, you may use this endpoint: [https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?access_token=[ACCESS_TOKEN]](https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?access_token=%5BACCESS_TOKEN%5D)

If the token is valid, you will have this kind of response:

```json
{
  "azp": "15[...]2b.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "aud": "15[...]2b.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "sub": "10[...]71",
  "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage",
  "exp": "1658865502",
  "expires_in": "3067",
  "access_type": "offline"
}
```

Else, you will have an error:

```json
{
  "error_description": "Invalid Value"
}
```

You may generate a new access token from the refresh token when the `expires_in` value is low or when the access token became invalid.
For example, with Axios:

```js
axios.post('https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token', {
  client_id: YOUR_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
  client_secret: YOUR_GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
  refresh_token: USER_GOOGLE_REFRESH_TOKEN,
  grant_type: 'refresh_token',
});
```

You will get a new access token:

```json
{
    "access_token": "ya[...]63",
    "expires_in": 3599,
    "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "id_token": "ey[...]bA"
}
```

If the authentication was revoked by the user, you will have an error in response:

```json
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "Token has been expired or revoked."
}
```